# How do I calculate the probability of 2 sets of random integers to intersect?

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose I draw two sets of random integers from 1 to 100. each using simple-random-sampling without replacement.  One is size 50 and the other is size 25.

How can I calculate the probability of the smaller set intersecting with the bigger one?

Comment: I have rolled the question back to its state just before it was substantially altered, so that the answers generously offered here will not be made irrelevant or confusing.

Comment: @whuber The situation is that the OP's question was ambiguous at the first post.  Then the first answerer edited it without confirming it with OP.  IMO I think the answerer should have consulted with OP first before editing it (in his own interpretation) and answering the question.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you.  This gives a nice case study demonstrating why it is best to close ambiguous questions as soon as possible.  Everybody then gets a chance to determine what the thread is going to be about before it (potentially) becomes confusing and frustrating.  Unfortunately, the site is gamified to encourage people to post answers hastily rather than taking the thought and time to curate a good question first: there are badges and reputation to be earned for posting quickly and almost nothing to be earned for useful comments and votes to close or reopen threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple intuition why you should get the hypergeometric distribution as answered by Ben:

The process is the same as having 100 white balls, colour a random selection of size 50 red, then put all 100 in an urn and sample 25 balls from that urn randomly without repetitions. The number of red balls in this process will be hypergeometric distributed.

Without using the formula for the hypergeometric distribution you can compute this more straightforward by multiplying the individual probabities each single draw. Ie. the probability to draw a red ball in the first draw, times the probability to draw a red ball in the second draw, etc.

$$P(\text{all red}) = \frac{50}{100}\frac{49}{99}\frac{48}{98} \dots \frac{26}{76} =  \frac{50!75!}{25!100!}$$

Comment: The question had been edited a bit but the strategy for the solution is the same for both versions of the question. The two probabilities are each other complement. The event that the set of size n2 is a subset of the set of size n1, is the same as the event that the set of size n2 has no intersection with the complement of the set of size n1.

Comment: The simplified, but less insightful, fraction is $Pr[\operatorname{all red}] = \frac{37}{70984652574}$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple problem, and it can be generalised easily to sets of any size.  For more general application, suppose your initial population has $N$ distinct objects and your samples are denoted as $\mathscr{S}_1$ and $\mathscr{S}_2$, containing $n_1$ and $n_2$ elements respectively.  Since each sample is taken without repetition of elements, the first sample will contain $n_1$ distinct elements and there will be $N-n_1$ unsampled elements.  The probability of a non-empty intersection is equal to the probability that the second sample contains any of these latter elements, which can be found using the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{Samples intersect})
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{S}_1 \cap \mathscr{S}_2 \neq \varnothing) \\[18pt]
&= 1-\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{S}_1 \cap \mathscr{S}_2 = \varnothing) \\[18pt]
&= 1-\text{Hyper}(0|N, n_1, n_2) \\[12pt]
&= 1-\frac{N-n_1 \choose n_2}{N \choose n_2} \\[6pt]
&= 1-\frac{(N-n_1)!}{n_2! (N-n_1-n_2)!} \cdot \frac{n_2! (N-n_2)!}{N!} \\[6pt]
&= 1-\frac{(N-n_1)! (N-n_2)!}{N! (N-n_1-n_2)!}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In your case you have $N=100$, $N_1=50$ and $n_2=25$ which gives:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{Samples intersect})
&= 1-\frac{(100-50)! (100-25)!}{100! (100-50-25)!} \\[6pt]
&= 1-\frac{50! \ 75!}{100! \ 25!} \\[12pt]
&= 1-5.212394 \times 10^{-10} \\[18pt]
&\approx 1. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I understand that for itersection the probility will be close to one. But in my original question I was trying to mean that n2 will be a subset of n1. (like all 25 of n2 being part of the 50 from n1)

Comment: @fcr13_8 Then you should roll back the edits and edit your question title.

Comment: At this point, since we have answered an entirely different question, I recommend you ask a new question for the subset query.  In future, please do not conflate different questions.